# Nohup run silenium webscraper in Ubuntu ec2

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, web-scraping, nohup, xvfb

I have a web scraper that uses selenium which I want to run on my Ubuntu EC2 in the background event after I log out, so I am trying to use `nohup`. The current code I have is:

**webscrape.py**:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

def main():

    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start() #starts vitual display

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    ...do the webscraping...

    driver.close()
    display.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

When I am logged in my EC2 and do `python webscrape.py` it runs normally. However, when I do `nohup python webscrape.py` and log out it stops. In the `nohup.out` log I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cruz/Scripts/WebScrape/google_brand_web_scraper.py", line 175, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cruz/Scripts/WebScrape/google_brand_web_scraper.py", line 120, in main
    website = GoogleBrandWebsiteScraper().brand_url_pull_from_google(i,driver) # get website for a brand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cruz/Scripts/WebScrape/google_brand_web_scraper.py", line 34, in brand_url_pull_from_google
    s = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 436, in page_source
    return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 171, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 379, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1007, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

So, apparently me logging out messes something up. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: You may want to try `screen`.  I'm not familiar with nohup to be able to figure out the issue you're having there, but `screen` should work.

Comment: @TimTisdall add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to try `screen`. I'm not familiar with nohup to be able to figure out the issue you're having there, but `screen` should work.

1. You run `screen` to create a new terminal that you can do your work in.
2. Run your code
3. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> followed by <kbd>d</kbd> to detach from that terminal (it will stay running in the background).
4. Running `screen -r` will re-attach to that terminal.

When you're "detached" from a terminal you can disconnect from a system and that detached terminal will continue running.  So, between steps 3 and 4 you can disconnect.

Comment: Can we create a bash script for this?
` #!/bin/bash
screen
python runmyscript.py
### Then somehow simulate Ctrl + a d ###### (How do we do this?)`

Comment: @AshishSharma What you have will run the command within `screen`, but I don't know about simulating a disconnect.  However, if you run that command and ACTUALLY disconnect, the command will continue to run and you can reconnect to it later with `screen -r`.